# Backtracing Queue

Tags: c, queue

I am placing game board moves into this queue, for the "parked car" game, and it should come out with 75 moves to solve the puzzle. However, the queue keeps overflowing, which results in a move not being enqueued, which makes the solution  more than 75 moves. Note: Cannot change the queue size, it is constant. Any ideas?

```
int enqueue(position* p){
Q[qrear] = p;
qrear = qrear + 1; 
if (qrear == QueueArraySize) {
    qrear = 0;
} 
qsize = qsize + 1;
return 0;
} /*End of insert()*/

position* dequeue(){
if (qsize == 0) {
    printf("Queue Underflow \n");
    return NULL;
}
else {
    position* temp = Q[qfront];
    qfront = qfront + 1; 
    if (qfront == QueueArraySize) {
        qfront = 0;
    }
    qsize = qsize - 1;
    return temp;
}
```

}

Comment: how you initialise Q?

Comment: And I would suggest passing the structure to Q in those functions, using global variables is not too good idea. struct that contains size, rear, front and size. And you should put NULL in Q[qfront] after you take it to temp.

Comment: @koper89 position* Q[QueueArraySize];

Comment: This is not allocation.

Comment: position Q[QueueArraySize] = {0, 0}; // This would be

Comment: @koper89: The items stored in the queue are pointers and the declaration allocates space for `QueueArraySize` pointers to `position`. (Of course they may be an issue that pointed-to positions are no longer valid when they are dequeued, but that's not an issue of the queue per se.)

Comment: It's allocating pointers, not what pointers are pointing at.

Comment: So what? Unless we see more of the program, we don't know whether that's an error. The queue code stores pointers.

Comment: When you store positions, you store pointers. Do the pointed-to positions exist throghout, so that they are still valid when they are dequeued? That may be an issue rather than the queue implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that qsize can get larger than QueueArraySize, but the number of items in the queue is limited to QueueArraySize.

enqueue cannot "fail", it always puts a position in the queue, and it always increments the queue size, even when it circles back to the beginning of Q (it might be overwriting positions at the beginning of the queue).

Another thing to consider is that you don't pay attention to the relationship between qrear and qfront. Imagine that QueueArraySize is 10, and you enqueue 12 positions, qfront will still point to Q[0] (since you haven't dequeued anything yet), but that is not the correct "front" of the queue since Q[0] and Q[1] have been overwritten by the 11th and 12th position you enqueued. In this case qfront should be Q[2]. You should move qfront if you are enqueuing into gfront, and you should move qrear if you are dequeuing from qrear.